# Block access to pages in cakePHP

Tags: acl, cakephp-2.2

How do I block access to any page in cakePHP. With page, I'm referring to actual views lying in the Page folder.

When I remove this line in, it works, but it also stops users from logging in. It would create a direct loop:

```
$this->Auth->allow('display');
```

Basically, when a user wants to view any page, and they are not logged in, they will be redirected to the login (`app/users/login`) page. After they've logged in, they will be directed to the page they last tried to access.

How would I go about this?

Comment: You need to allow the login page `$this->Auth->allow('login');`, while the display page should be denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your situation is that *all* pages shown by the pagesController are the *same* action (`display()`), only using a different parameter (the page to display). You can therefore not block access to the display action, because that will block access to *all* pages.

If the number of pages is limited, then the easiest way to implement this is `ControllerAuthorize`. Read the documentation here; [Using ControllerAuthorize](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize)

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array('authorize' => 'Controller'),
    );
    public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
        // Make all actions public 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, inside your pages controller;

```
class PagesController extends AppController {

    public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
        if ('display' !== $this->request->action) {
            // other actions; let he AppController handle access
            return parent::isAuthorized($user);
        }

        if (!empty($user)) {
            // Logged-in users have access to any page
            return true;
        }

        $page = empty($this->request->params['pass'][0]) ? null : $this->request->params['pass'][0];

        switch($page) {
            case 'home':
            case 'about':
            // etc
               return true;
        }

        // all other pages are 'private'
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just an example, of course, modify to fit your needs

Comment: I fixed it two weeks ago but haven't had time to post my solution. Yours is spot on though and is the exact solution that I used.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it fixed already, in which case you may find your solution 'confirmed' to be the (a) right approach.

Comment: I'm glad it's the right approach. I always thought modifying code that came with a clean cakePHP install is rather risky and 'dirty'. But realised that sometimes, it's needed.

Comment: A clean CakePHP install is just the 'Boilerplating' to get you started. Taking that as a startingpoint, you'll build your application to your needs. The default `PagesController::display()` is mainly there for convenience (to quickly add some static pages). Because most websites are database-driven, they will store the *content* of the pages inside a database, including (for example)  access-permissions. It really depends on your use. If your website starts to grow, this may be worth considering. Otherwise you can always give it a try 'as excercise' to improve your skills.

Answer (score 0):

use 
      $this->Auth->allow('\','display');
it allow all after '\' pages..
or 
if you not allow except display page you do nothing.